# Is XElement's add operation Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, concurrency, linq-to-xml, thread-safety, xelement

Is it safe to Add child elements to an XElement via its ADD  method in a parallel way (as in a parallel foreach)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual
>   Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

In other words, no, the `add` method is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Recent (painful) experience leads me to think that it is very, VERY thread un-safe.

I analyzed a couple of dump files that contained 7.4 **million** and 8.8 million extra unwanted XElement instances respectively. As best I can determine, they got created when some innocuous-looking code involving manipulating the sub-nodes of an XElement (including calling Add() in some cases) got called from two thread pool threads at the same time.

This isn't too surprising - XElement and the associated classes are implemented using linked-list-like structures, and if you scramble the link references a variety of weird results can ensue - loops, unattached fragments, etc.